how to scrub animation in viewer using shortcut?
I'm in 3d viewer and I want to scrub my animation without have to click/drag on the timeline. For example in Maya :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDZEhzH1zGQ
I found the similar one in Blender using ALT + mouse wheel. But If I have long animation then I have to scroll the mouse wheel a lot and this make my finger tired. I'm looking the one like in that video, where I can use modifier key and a mouse drag anywhere on the viewer (or pen drag if using digitizer/wacom) .
Is it possible ?
